# Unable to search a string with whitespace between words using Google custom search api and python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-custom-search

I am trying to fetch results from Google Custom Search API using Python 3 (Spyder IDE-Anaconda). I have set the api key and the custom search engine(cse) code.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
 from googleapiclient.discovery import build
 import pprint

 my_api_key = "XXXXX"
 my_cse_id = "XXXX"

 service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=my_api_key)
 res = service.cse().list(q="QueryString", cx=my_cse_id, num=5).execute()
 results= res['items']

 for result in results:
      pprint.pprint(result)
```

The code works fine when I give only one word as the "QueryString" input (for eg. `q="Donald"`) but fails to give any results when two or more words are given together (for eg. `q="Donald Jackson"` or `q="Donald Jackson LinkedIn"`)

I have tried to use `+` operator as `q="Donald"+"Jackson"+"LinkedIn"` but still the same problem remains.

Please advise